# JPA/Hibernate error: 'No data type for node' error message

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

For the following JPA Query:

```
Emp e = (Emp) em.createQuery("SELECT emp FROM Addr a INNER JOIN a.emp 
WHERE a.city=:city").setParameter("city", "whatever").getSingleResult();
```

i get the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'emp' {originalText=emp}

Emp and Addr are Entity Classes, with One(Emp) to Many(Addr), relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... found the solution, the query should look like:

```
SELECT a.emp FROM Addr a INNER JOIN a.emp 
WHERE a.city=:city"
```

Note, the a.emp in SELECT clause, as against only emp.